# MYSQL Delimiter error in procedure

Tags: mysql, navicat

I trying to create procedure with IF blocks and IF() function. I always give an 1064 error. That's my code:

```
delimiter $$
drop procedure if exists sp_test$$
create procedure sp_test (p_a int,p_b int,p_c int)
BEGIN
    insert into test (a,b,c) values (IF(IFNULL(p_a ,0)<=0, NULL, p_a ),p_b ,p_c );
END$$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: I tested your code on MySQL 5.6.31, and it works without error for me. When you ask a question about an error, please include the full error message you got. There are important clues in the message.

Comment: Also share with us how you are executing these statements. DELIMITER is recognized only by the MySQL command-line client, so if you're using an API or MySQL Workbench or something, it won't be necessary, or supported.

Comment: I solved it only by replacing mysql client.
 Navicat -> Heidi SQL

That was minimal test sentence that raise error in navicat